# Sort array by percentage but if user has same percentage sort by kills

Tags: node.js

So I am sorting an array with;

```
let userDataWinSorted = userDataWinsFiltered.sort((a,b) => Math.floor((b.wins/(b.wins+b.loses))) - Math.floor((a.wins/(a.wins+a.loses))));
```

But it lets say;

jon has 5 wins 0 loses
and andy has 10 wins 0 loses

In the sort jon will come ahead of andy because jon is just first in the array.

How can I sort the array by percentage BUT ALSO account for kills when two people have the same percentage? So that any will be above jon in this case.

Comment: Still more clarification?? Post your original data and sorted data(what you want)

Comment: I don't know how to clarify it more...

Jon: 3/0*100 = 100%
Andy: 7/0*100 = 100%

With just using the sorted in OP jon can be above andy in the sorted array. I need to account for kills in my sorting IF both players have the same percent...

Comment: You can put your explanation into an equation - `if` comes in handy - if there the same account kills else better ratio

Answer (score 0):

```
const sortWithPercentageAndKills = (a, b) => {
  if (a.percentage === b.percentage) {
    return a.kills - b.kills;
  }
  return a.percentage - b.percentage;
}

const sortedArray = inputArray.sort(sortWithPercentageAndKills);
```

Answer (score 0):

When the first comparator for winloss% returns 0 (meaning the elements are equal), you need to use another comparator for kills:

```js
function num_compar_gen(key) {
  return function(a, b) {
    if (a[key] > b[key]) {
      return -1;
    } else if (a[key] < b[key]) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  }
}

const kill_compar = num_compar_gen('kills');
const winloss_compar = num_compar_gen('winloss_pcnt');

const users = [{
    win: 5,
    loss: 10,
    winloss_pcnt: 0.50,
    kills: 100
  },
  {
    win: 2,
    loss: 1,
    winloss_pcnt: 2.00,
    kills: 100
  },
  {
    win: 50,
    loss: 10,
    winloss_pcnt: 5.00,
    kills: 100
  },
  {
    win: 5,
    loss: 10,
    winloss_pcnt: 0.50,
    kills: 1000
  }
];

var sorted = users.sort(function(a, b) {
  var n = winloss_compar(a, b);
  if (n === 0) n = kill_compar(a, b);
  return n;
});

console.log(sorted);
```